# Virtual environment is not working in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

I am deploying my Django app on digitalocean but I get an error after the giving the command in my terminal to migrate. Help me to figure out the error so that I can fix.

**terminal output**

```
urban@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~$ source bin/activate
(urban) urban@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~$ cd lok
(urban) urban@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/lok$ python manage.py migrate
File "manage.py", line 14
) from exc
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
(urban) urban@ubuntu-s-1vcpu-1gb-blr1-01:~/lok$ ls
business    List     manage.py  news       sports             
templates
db.sqlite3  lokswar  movie      README.md  static_my_project
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of Django requires Python 3, but it looks like `python` is `python2`, even after activating the virtual environment. You can use `which python` to check that `python` is pointing to the executable in your virtual environment.

If your virtual environment was created with python 2, then you'll have to [create a new virtual environment](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) that uses python 3.

```
deactivate
python3 -m venv /path/to/urban.new
source /path/to/urban.new/bin/activate
# install requirements
```